# How to use value of a variable from a loop in a void method

Tags: java, object

In the 2 similar methods with measure in their name, they output the data that I want to have output in the last method many times. But if I try to simply call them in the last method the message does not work anymore. I also have another class with a main method where I create an object that calls the last method as many times as needed. Here is the code.

```
public class Weatherstation{
    
    double temperature; 
    double windspeed;
    double windChillTemperature;
    double actualTemperature;
    double actualSpeed;
    
    public void measureTemperature(){
    
        for (temperature = -10; temperature <= 30; temperature = temperature + 5)
        {
            System.out.println(temperature);
            if(temperature == 30)
                 while(temperature > -10)
                 {
                     System.out.println(temperature-1);
                     temperature = temperature - 1;
                     
                 }
        }
                 
}
    
    public void measureWindspeed(){
       
        for (windspeed = 0; windspeed <= 80; windspeed = windspeed + 8)
        {
            System.out.println(windspeed);
            if(windspeed == 80)
                 while(windspeed > 0)
                 {
                     System.out.println(windspeed-16);
                     windspeed = windspeed-16;
                 }
        }
}
        
    public void calculateWindChillTemperature(){
        
        windChillTemperature = 13.12 + (0.6215 * temperature) + ((0.3965 * temperature) - 11.37) * Math.pow(windspeed, 0.16);
        
}
    
    public void  generateWeatherMessage(){
        
        String warning="";
        calculateWindChillTemperature();
        if(windspeed >= 70)
            warning += "Wind Warning";
        if(windChillTemperature >= -18)
            warning += "Cold Warning";
        System.out.println("Actual weather: Temp: "+temperature+"°C (Wind: "+windspeed+"km/h) Chilltemp: "+windChillTemperature+"°C, "+warning);
}
    
      
}

public class WeatherstationTester {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Weatherstation w1 = new Weatherstation();
        for(int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
            w1.generateWeatherMessage();
        
            
        
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not passing any information into Weatherstation to calculate, so all the variables are zero.

Add a constructor like so:

```
public Weatherstation(double temperature, double windspeed, double windChillTemperature, double actualTemperature, double actualSpeed) {
    this.temperature = temperature;
    this.windspeed = windspeed;
    this.windChillTemperature = windChillTemperature;
    this.actualTemperature = actualTemperature;
    this.actualSpeed = actualSpeed;
}
```

Then modify your test class to pass in the variables:

```
public class WeatherstationTester {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
            Weatherstation w1 = new Weatherstation(i, i, i, i, i);
            w1.generateWeatherMessage();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But how could I pass info using the methods that I have written there ?